# How to integrate react-native-tab-view using expo?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, I need a bit help in integrating a library [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view). Can I get a step by step guide how to integrate it with a new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run the following command in terminal

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

Paste this in your App.js and you will be done

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TabView, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';

const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }]} />
);

const SecondRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }]} />
);

const initialLayout = { width: Dimensions.get('window').width };

export default function TabViewExample() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'first', title: 'First' },
    { key: 'second', title: 'Second' },
  ]);

  const renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: SecondRoute,
  });

  return (
    <TabView
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={initialLayout}
    />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scene: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```